# std::cin infinite loop from invalid input

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, cin

Please read the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Please input one integer." << std::endl;
    int i;
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> i;
        if (std::cin) {
            std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error. Please try again."<< std::endl;
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::cin.clear();
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Thank you very much." << std::endl;
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I give std::cin an invalid input, such as `w`, then `Error. Please try again.` is outputed infinitely.
I thought `std::cin.ignore` would blank the input stream, and `std::cin.clear` would resume it to normal state. So why does the infinite loop happen?

Comment: `clear` first. `ignore` second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `std::basic_istream::ignore()` ignores only 1 character:

```
basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
```

(From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

More idiomatic use for your case seems to be the one from the example there:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Also, note that you want to call `clear()` before the `ignore()` call, so the input extraction of `ignore()` will succeed instead of returning immediately.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much!